# My cron job does not work

Tags: cron, cpanel

I am using cpanel here is i set a cron

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.mysite.com/cron.php?para1=value&para2=value2
```

This is not work but only one time i received email like that.

```
Resolving mysite.com... *ip address*  
Connecting to mysite.com|*ip address*|:80... connected.  
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK  
Length: 164 [text/html]  
Saving to: `/dev/null'  

0K    100% 7.11M=0s
```

please guide me about this.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: run a file cron.php via url. cron.php had some parameters which values are giving through url.

Comment: I mean: your script seems to download a file using `wget` to directly send it to `/del/null`, is that what you want? Did you try `echo`ing a timestamp in a file (say `/tmp/cron_stamp` for instance) to check if it works?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent version of cPanel you will be executing your cronjobs through jailshell (unless your cPanel account has Normal bash shell enabled).  Because of this you need to:

1. Use absolute paths to your commands.
2. Use curl as wget is not enabled in jailshell.

Below is a modified command using absolute paths and to use curl instead of wget:

```
/usr/bin/curl http://www.mysite.com/cron.php?para1=value&para2=value2 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

You can remove the " >/dev/null 2>&1 " to enable the output of the command and source of whatever url that is being checked to be emailed to you.